# Efficient way to pick up pairwise vertices of certain Euclidean distance in arbitrarily dimensional coordinates?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a grid graph with `x` and `y` vertices in each direction. The 2-dimensional coordinates of the graph `vtc` are the following:

```
x = 5;
y = 3;
vtc = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[#, 2] &@ Table[{i, j}+# &/@Tuples[{0, 1}, 2], {j, 0, y-2}, {i, 0, x-2}];
```

Then I generalize the `vtc` coordinate into higher dimensions (similar to the concept of hypercube. The generalization function I defined is `highvtcoords`:

```
highvtcoords[lis_, d_] := (
    coordinate = lis;
    For[kkk = 2, kkk < d, kkk++,
       vtcoords = Distribute[{coordinate, {0, 1}}, List];
      coordinate = Flatten[#, 1] & /@ vtcoords;
     ];
    Return[coordinate];
  )
```

Each coordinate has a vertex `vi` (i=1,2,3,...). Then I want to pick up pairs of vertices where their Euclidean distance is a pre-defined `Distance`. I traverse all the coordinates with for-loops and check the distance. Here is the example:

```
Distance = 2; (*this can be arbitrary number*)
dim=2; (*dimensions*)
highvtc = highvtcoords[vtc, dim]; (*generalize coordinates to high dimension*)

(*assign each coordinate to a labeled vertice vi*)
vertices = Flatten[Table[Subscript[v, i], {i, 1, Length[highvtc]}]];

 pairselect = {};
 For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[highvtc], ii++,
  For[jj = ii + 1, jj <= Length[highvtc], jj++,
   
     If[EuclideanDistance[highvtc[[ii]], highvtc[[jj]]] == Distance, 
          AppendTo[pairselect, {vertices[[ii]], vertices[[jj]]}];
       ];
    ];
  ];
```

**Question:**

> When `x` and `y` are large or `dim` goes large, is there an efficient way to pick up vertices which meet the constraint `EuclideanDistance[vi,vj]==Distance`? how to get rid of using for-loops?

note: when `Distance=1, dim=2`, one might use `NearestNeighborGraph` to do the task as follows (but I don't consider this at the moment):

```
g = NearestNeighborGraph[highvtc];
pairlists = EdgeList[g] /. UndirectedEdge -> List;
pairtemp = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[pairlists, 1]];
replaces = {};
For[kk = 1, kk <= Length[pairtemp], kk++,
    AppendTo[replaces, pairtemp[[kk]] -> vertices[[kk]]];
  ];
pairselect1 = pairlists /. replaces;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just use the built-in [`DistanceMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix.html) - it's going to be a lot more efficient that manually writing loops.

Comment: You could also use `RelationGraph` as follows:
```With[{distance = 2}, 
 EdgeList[RelationGraph[EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] == distance &, 
    vtc,DirectedEdges -> False]] /. UndirectedEdge -> List]```

Comment: What about using `Nearest` or `NearestNeighborGraph` to find all points of distance $\leq r$ then the just sieve out those with distance $<r$?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, if so, can I still automatically get the assigned label vi into a list?

Comment: @flinty, thank you. `RelationGraph` is nice. But still, it seems that I have to do at least one loop to map the assigned vertice `vi` to the selected pairwise coordinate (such as {0,0}->v1, {2,0}->v5, for {v1,v5}) (later I want to use the variable `vi` in some defined function such as `f[a_,b_]:=1+a*b` )?

Comment: @Xuemei *vertex not vertice. You don't need any loops. A simple modification should help: 
```EdgeList[
   RelationGraph[EuclideanDistance[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]] == distance &, 
    Transpose@{Range@Length@vtc, vtc}, DirectedEdges -> False]
   ][[All, All, 1]] /. UndirectedEdge -> List``` That gets you: `{{1, 5}, {1, 11}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {3, 12}, {4, 8}, {5, 9}, {5, 
  13}, {6, 10}, {7, 14}, {9, 15}, {11, 13}, {12, 14}, {13, 15}}`

Comment: you are right. that's a very good point! thank you@flinty

Comment: Erm. Just had a closer look at your code. Unless you are using Mathematica versio 12.3 or later, _do not use `AppendTo`. In pre 12.3, it copies the whole list in each iteration.

Comment: @flinty, thank you! just one more question. In this case, lets say we have the pairwise list `pairwiseV={{1,5},{1,11},...}` now. Then I just do one-loop for the defined Iterative function `f[expr_,a_,b_]:=(exprtemp=Expand[expr*(1+a*b)];  exprtemp = exprtemp /. {_^n_ -> 0}; Return[exprtemp])`. As an example, `initial = 1; For[ii=1,ii<=Length[lis],ii++, For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[pairwiseV], ii++, initial =f[initial , vertices[[pairwiseV[[ii]][[1]]]], vertices[[pairwiseV[[ii]][[2]]]]];  ];]`. Do you think one can do it in a smart way?

Comment: @Xuemei don't use loops. use `Map` instead.

Comment: `Map` together with `Nest`? @flinty

Comment: the reason for using the last loop is because of the function `f[expr_,a_,b_]`. I have to iterate `f` with variables. @flinty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 10;
pts = Tuples[Subdivide[0., 1., n], 2];
labels = Table[Indexed[v, i], {i, 1, Length[pts]}];
r = N[Sqrt[1^2 + 2^2]/n];
eps = 1. 10^-12
select = With[{
    lower = (1 - eps) r,
    upper = (1 + eps) r
    },
   Select[lower <= #[[2]] <= upper &]
   ];
indexpairs = Join @@ MapIndexed[
    Thread[{#2[[1]], select[#1][[All, 1]]}] &,
    Nearest[pts -> {"Index", "Distance"}, 
     pts, {\[Infinity], r (1 + eps)}]
    ];
labelpairs = Partition[labels[[Flatten[indexpairs]]], 2];

Graphics[{
  Black, Dotted,
  Line[Partition[pts[[Flatten[indexpairs]]], 2]],
  PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[pts],
  }]
```

[image]

This should work quite descently. Of course, with a regular grid, everything is quite predictable. So it should be possible to generate only those pairs that are actually needed.

Comment: thank you for the example. nice graph! btw, in your code `vertices` probably means `labels`. For regular grid, it should work very well, I am also not sure unregular case, ha.

Comment: This will work also in the nonregular case, because it uses `Nearest` which works for arbitrary point clouds.

Comment: After I obtain the pairwised lables such as `{v1,v2}`, how can one efficiently apply a iteratation function `f[expr_,a_,b_]:=(exprtemp=Expand[expr*(1+a*b)];  exprtemp = exprtemp /. {_^n_ -> 0}; Return[exprtemp])`? There `a` and `b` are replaced by the elements in the pairwised lables, such as `f0=1; For[ii=1,ii<=Length[labelpairs],ii++, f0=f[f0, labelpairs[[ii]][[1]], labelpairs[[ii]][[2]]] ;]`.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you want to do something like this: `f = {expr, X} \[Function] 
   Expand[expr (1 + Indexed[X, 1] Indexed[X, 2])] /. Power[_, n_] :> 0;
f0 = Fold[f, 1, labelpairs];`.

Comment: ha, yes. thank you! somehow it takes very long time to calculate. when compared to for-loop, it somehow does not speed up a lot. I am not sure whether there are any efficient way.

Comment: It is slow probably because you do the calculations symbolically. Should be faster if you numericize your labels before all the computations.